# деплой node.js на heroku (ошибка Procfile)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, heroku

Всем привет. Пытаюсь выгрузить свое MERN приложение на heroku сервер, но из за ошибки Procfile получается невалидное приложение которое не отображается на сайте.

```
Procfile
  web : yarn --require 'dotenv/config'  babel-node server/app.js
```

Команды которыми я запускаю приложение локально

```
 yarn --require 'dotenv/config'  babel-node server/app.js //запуск сервера
 webpack-dev-server --debug --hot --devtool eval-source-map --output-pathinfo --watch --colors --inline --content-base public //запуск react приложения
```

Comment: Выполните команду `yarn` (она же `yarn install`) перед командой `yarn --require 'dotenv/config'  babel-node server/app.js` - она установит зависимости. Добавьте детали ошибки, не совсем понятно что не так.

Comment: Вот лог heroku
  2018-12-11T14:45:42.391999+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: yarn install yarn --require 'dotenv/config'  babel-node server/app.js`
2018-12-11T14:45:45.730197+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-12-11T14:45:45.710117+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
Если нужно что-то конкретное, вы пишите, я просто в этих сервисах и бекенде новичек)

Comment: Давно не имел дела с heroku, по этому точного ответа дать не могу, но раз state changed to crashed, значит нужно смотреть логи и выяснять детали.

Comment: Там всё что угодно может быть, например порты не правильно указаны. Вам нужно погуглить, как получить доступ к логам того процесса, который у вас падает. Скорее всего это можно сделать через ту же утилиту, через которую вы к heroku подключаетесь.

Answer (score 0):

Подождите, зачем вам babel-node на продакшене, если ваш сборщик (видимо webpack) должен сначал сбилдить проект к примеру в папку dist, которую вы уже и должны лить на heroku. Вот вам пример одного из моих проектов. Не совсем то, что вам нужно, но думаю вы поймёте что к чему. Отрывок из конфига вебпака

```
entry: './client/src/index.ts', 
    devtool: 'source-map',
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'project.bundle.js'
    },entry: './client/src/index.ts', 
    devtool: 'source-map',
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'project.bundle.js'
    },
```

Вот Procfile настроек heroku `web: cp -r client/assets dist/assets/ && cp -r client/vendor dist/vendor/ && node .`